# Importrange function returning blank cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using the sheet it was working good but suddenly my 5th column has become blank don't know how but tried to fix but failed

```
=QUERY(
{
importrange("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=492691616","Asim!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=420290061","Himani Ma'am!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1739869159","Amar Sir!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=379284517","Prihaans Sir!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1628909160","Awadhesh Sir!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1178416768","Sudhir Sir!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1834389652","Akash Sir!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1314407625","Shahbaz!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=56464192","Rakesh!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1717733476","Shreeneil!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1206173219","Shubham!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=223854930&fvid=240899642","Paytm!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=961699629","Bank Transferred!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=495755553","Razor Pay!A2:J");
IMPORTRANGE("1vEK5DI4GSAWL-OIRP7iLFKyOJXZ6Iv_HV4OEiEgY-78/edit#gid=1432805879","Vinay!A2:J")
},
"select * where Col1 is not Null")
```

Comment: It is probably to do with the data you have added, but without seeing the data, it doesn't seem possible to know why. Can you share a sample sheet that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `query()` function will only accept one data type per column. The column's type is determined by the majority of values within the first few hundred rows. Data that does not match the column's type will be returned as null.

If column E in the 'Asim' sheet is completely or almost completely blank, it is possible that the column type will be `null`, with the result that all data in column 5 of all the imported ranges will be returned as null.

You can check whether this is the case by filling column E in sheet Asim with some value like zero, the letter A, or `=today()`, depending on whether the column is supposed to contain numbers, text or dates.